# How to use variables in Grafana to exclude list of label names when retrieving data?

Tags: regex, grafana

I'm looking for a way to exclude some label names from the query by using variables in **Grafana**.

Current query:

```
rate(http_request_duration_seconds_sum{container="$container", namespace="$namespace"}[5m]) / rate(http_request_duration_seconds_count{container="$container", namespace="$namespace"}[5m])
```

We can do it by just adding it to the current query in the following way:

```
rate(http_request_duration_seconds_sum{container="$container", namespace="$namespace",exported_endpoint=~"/management/health.*"}[5m]) / rate(http_request_duration_seconds_count{container="$container", namespace="$namespace",exported_endpoint=~"/management/health.*"}[5m])
```

The query above excludes all of the '`exported_endpoint`' label that starts with `'/management/health'`.

That query has two critical issues:

- it's hard-coded instead of using variable.
- we cannot use list of excluded names, in the future we might want to exclude more endpoints.

What do you suggest?

Comment: Your query includes (regexp matching is used) , not excludes. So what you need? exclude (filter selected out) or include (filter selected).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no limitation on using variables in regex-matchers. Basically Grafana will substitute it before sending request to Prometheus.

So, you can use something like

```
metric{label1="$label1", label2=~"$label2_filter"}
metric{label1="$label1", label2!~"$label2_filter_exclude"}
```

About the excision of multiple labels: if you use '!~' to exclude labels, you always can use something like `filter1_.*|filter2_.*` or even `${filter1}|${filter2}` where `filter1` and `filter2` are variables in grafana.